# How to display html code stored in a field in mongodb

Tags: html, mongodb

I have stored some HTML code in a field in mongodb,
my question is how to display it, when i retrieve it
and display inside  <%= %> it is showing just html code;
I tried with eval() but it's not working.
if i put like this in .ejs file

```
 <div id="googlemap">
   <div style="width: 100%">
     <%=hospital.map%>   
  </div>
```

**result is given below; it just shows html code on the page.**

City: MUMBAI
Location:

```
<div class="mapouter"><div class="gmap_canvas"><iframe width="600" height="500" id="gmap_canvas" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?q=hiranandani%20hospital&t=&z=13&ie=UTF8&iwloc=&output=embed" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0"></iframe><a href="https://www.pureblack.de"></a></div><style>.mapouter{text-align:right;height:500px;width:600px;}.gmap_canvas {overflow:hidden;background:none!important;height:500px;width:600px;}</style></div>
```

Can someone please help?
Anurag

Answer (score 0):

I am also fairly new to MangoDB. But, have you tried to loop through the contents of the database before you display the result? 
Maybe try something like:

```
  <div id="googlemap">
       <div style="width: 100%">
       <% hospitals.forEach(function(hospital){ %>
         <%=hospital.map%>   
       <% }); ?>
      </div>
    </div>
```

You can also check that the is no confusion in how you are using the tags

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am returning only one hospital so loop won't work; in hospital.map I already stored some html code; when i am trying to load it, it's showing code as output instead of displaying map. i tried using innerHTML also; but result is same.

Comment: Oh okay I see. If you are still busy with this task, can you provide more information or sample code.